# WordPress won't render links in a post using absolute URI

Tags: wordpress, permissions, hyperlink

I have inherited a site with a slew of issues, one of which has me stumped (note: I am not a WordPress expert, so this could be a stupid question).

When my users create a blog post and use the link builder, they are creating links with the "from existing content" option, which simply embeds a fully formed (permalink) url. It saves, and they carry on. However, when the post is rendered to the public, the link is not rendered. Double check the admin, and the link is still in the post, so it's not getting stripped, but I can imagine what (or why) would disable the link from being rendered. It's not that the text isn't hyperlinked. The text doesn't show up at all. Viewing the source shows it's non-existent.

Is this something anyone else has seen?

**More Info**

I can get the links to show up if I modify the url in the href to be a relative path. The absolute path is failing... odd.

Comment: Nevermind on those two plugins. Dead end.

Comment: [Take a look at this Q](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/current-shortcode-detect-currently-used-shortcode) and A.

Answer (score 1):

Disable all plugins and see if the problem goes away. If so, re-enable them one at a time until you find the culprit.

If that doesn't work it's probably your theme. You can verify this by switching to the default theme and see if that fixes it. You would then want to search through your theme files (particularly functions.php) for any `add_filter` function calls. The culprit is likely `add_filter('the_content', 'some function thats stripping the links')`

Let me know if that doesn't work for ya.